# Issue of command line on mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-prompt

This is what I see when I enter "echo `$PATH` on my MacBook.

[image: This is what I see when I enter "echo $PATH" on my MacBook.]

What does this mean and how is it different from the normal usr/local/bin path?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 0):

In short, the `$PATH` variable will show the list of directories where your command prompt should search for executable files to run.

Let's assume you have the program `/a/directory/my_program` and your PATH is something like: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/a/directory/`

If you enter `my_program` from *any* directory, it will execute. This is because it found `my_program` within one of the listed directories from the `$PATH` variable.

You can find more information on the [$PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) variable here.